# ReactJS: Clear radio button when clicked again

Tags: reactjs

I have the follow radiogroup:

```
<RadioGroup value={item.packingLocation} 
onChange={e => {
const val = e.target.value
UpdateCheckbox2(val, item)
}}>
<FormControlLabel value="label1" control={<Radio color="primary" />} label="Label 1" />
<FormControlLabel value="label2" control={<Radio color="primary" />} label="Label 2" />
</RadioGroup>
```

```
const UpdateCHeckbox2 = (val, item) => {
    const getdataaa = [...meaweig]
    const onedataaaa = getdataaa.map(el => {
      return {
        ...el,
        Weight: el.Weight.map(e => {
          if (e.label == item.label) {
            return {
              ...e,
              packingLocation: val
            }
          } else {
            return {
              ...e,
            }
          }
        })
      }
    })
```

What I want to do is allow the user to click again on the radio to unselect it - how can I do this? I tried attaching a onclick to the label for e.target.value to check but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-radio-group ?

Comment: No - just MaterialUI

Comment: @PaulVI you can find out working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/uncheck-radio-uuiy1?fontsize=14&file=/demo.js)

Comment: That works well (in that you can unselect the radio) ... but clicking the radio turns them all to that value. I display these in a .map

Comment: Do you want checkboxes instead of radio buttons?

Comment: No, they need to be radio buttons as the user can only select one option

Comment: Also, they cannot match via Value as mentioned these radio buttons are within a map (so all values are the same) - which is why it is checking all of the radio buttons (and unchecking them) - is there another way of doing this?